# Java PECS fail for list of parametrized classes

Tags: java

Consider I have class named A, class B extends A and class C extends A. I have a method

```java
public static void listMethod(List<? extends A> list){

}
```

To this method I can pass any List of A subclasses and A class itself. But if I introduce next class:

```java
class Holder<T>{
    private final T val;

    public Holder(T val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public T getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

And also change my method to:

```java
public static void listMethod(List<Holder<? extends A>> list){

}
```

I can't pass to this method any of `List<Holder<A>>`, `List<Holder<B>>` or `List<Holder<C>>`
Why does this happen, and how do I change my method or my classes so I will be able to pass List of Holders

Comment: Your Method say. That every `Holder<? extends A>` allowed is. I assume that `B` and `C` not extend `A`. Your Solution could be an Interface wich A, B and C implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As pecs says ? must extend type that your list will return. So next method works fine:

```
public static void listMethod(List<? extends Holder<? extends A>> list){

}
```